# is it well defined which thread calls constructors of thread_local storage?

Tags: c++, multithreading, language-lawyer

does the c++ standard define how, when and by which thread the constructors of thread_local variables are called? Is it for example always the thread itself for which the thread_local data is allocated? or maybe it's the thread that spawns the new thread? or the first thread of the process? or maybe it's up to the compiler?

Comment: Thread local variables are just that - there's a copy for each thread. The constructor for a particular thread is called in the context of that thread, before the variable is first accessed (usually when the thread starts up).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [basic.start.dynamic] It is implementation-defined whether the dynamic initialization of a non-local non-inline variable with thread storage duration is sequenced before the first statement of the initial function of a thread or is deferred. If it is deferred, the initialization associated with the entity for thread *t* is sequenced before the first non-initialization odr-use by *t* of any non-inline variable with thread storage duration defined in the same translation unit as the variable to be initialized. **It is implementation-defined in which threads and at which points in the program such deferred dynamic initialization occurs**.